# How do you combine two split data back into original (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data named `Total` and I split it into features and labels as below. Later I split them into training and test data.

```
Total_X = Total[:,:-1]
Total_y = Total[:,-1]

Train_X , Test_X , Train_y, Test_y = train_test_split(Total_X,Total_y,test_size = .3)
```

Now I want to combine `Train_X` and `Train_y` and create a new list which is like `Total`.

Comment: `np.column_stack((Train_X,Train_Y))`?

Comment: Any recombining you do will result in a copy. Can you show the implementation of train_test_split?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you wanted to divide them in the first place?

```
test_len = np.floor(len(Total) * 0.3)
test_xy, train_xy = Total[:test_len], Total[test_len:]
```

And then if you need them, you can extract `test_x = test_xy[:,:-1]` etc